# Grails: Best approach for storing data for the duration of the users session

Tags: session, grails, controller, domain-model, user-data

Which of the following methods is considered the recommended way of storing data in grails for the duration of a users session?

1. Store a bunch of individual variables in the actual session.
2. Store a domain model class object in the session.
3. Use a session scoped controller and store the variables as controller fields or properties.
4. Use a session scoped controller and store the data as a domain model class object stored in the controller.
5. Some other way that I have not thought of yet.

Comment: I will not store individual variables, or whole domain object. Rather have map stored in session ! Or a custom object which has properties for the things you want to store in session. You may utilize session scoped services too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use session-scoped services for this sort of thing. With this approach you inject a proxy for your session scoped service into a globally scoped service (or controller), which means you don't need to worry about keeping track of the stuff you put into the session.

There's a nice little tutorial [here](http://ldaley.com/post/436635056/scoped-services-proxies-in-grails) that shows you how to mix differently-scoped services. And it looks like the author of that tutorial has also written a plugin to make the process easier (I haven't actually tried the plugin though).

EDIT:

Here's an example showing how you'd set this up & actually use a service proxy to pass stuff to your view:

Create a service that's going to hold your session-scoped stuff, like a user shopping cart or whatever. It's just a regular service (that references other services etc), but you can store session-specific stuff as member variables -

```
class MySessionScopedService {

    def currentUser
    def shoppingCart

    ...

}
```

In `resources.groovy`, set up a session-scoped proxy for your service. Rather than directly injecting `MySessionScopedService` into other services, you'll be injecting a proxy for it.

```
beans = {
    mySessionScopedServiceProxy(org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean) {
        targetBeanName = 'mySessionScopedService'
        proxyTargetClass = true
    }
}
```

Finally, when you want to reference your service, you reference the proxy (notice I'm referencing `mySessionScopedServiceProxy` rather than `mySessionScopedService`). You can reference the proxy in any globally-scoped component and at runtime, Spring will inject the correct one for the current session.

```
class MyController {
    def mySessionScopedServiceProxy
    def someOtherService

    def index() {
        [shoppingCart: mySessionScopedServiceProxy.shoppingCart, currentUser: mySessionScopedServiceProxy.currentUser]
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you recommend passing the data stored in the service to a view?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an example

Answer (score 0):

As sudhir already pointed out, a map stored directly in the session is for me the easiest and most expected way.